# Junk text along side html due to django template blocks?

Tags: html, django, utf-8, django-templates

I have a template block to override the class name in the inherited template. The resultant html from the block override is showing up the a malicious text.

**Base.html:**

```
<html>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    <h1 class="{% block heading_style %}Base{% endblock %}">Base Page Heading</h1> 
    {% endblock%}
</body>
</html>
```

**Child.html:**

```
{% extends "Base.html" %}

{% block content %} 
{{block.super}}
{% block heading_style %}Login{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

The block heading_style is the block I'm concerned about.

**Resultant html:**

[image: Resultant html]

As you can see the h1 class has been replaced with "Login" but it has also the started showing the "Login" as text after the h1 tag.

I'm using django 1.3.3 and eclipse with pydev. I've also checked the encoding of the html files and they and they are `utf-8`

Comment: I don't think malicious means what you think it means (insert Inigo Montoya gif here...) It means something done on purpose to be harmful. I can't see anything in your question that could refer to that.

Comment: My bad, but I hope you got the question, I cant really think of a reason is to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the definition of the `heading_style` block in the child *within* the `content` block. So it's being used for two things: as text content within `content`, and to fill the `heading_style` block in the parent.

Move `heading_style` outside of the `content` block definition, and it should be fine.

Comment: I was suspecting that, so I moved it out and it went away. Thanks for the answer Dan.

Answer (score 0):

one endblock is missing

```
{% block content %} 
{{block.super}}
{% block heading_style %}Login{% endblock %} {% endblock %}
```

Comment: wopse!! my bad. I've closed the block but made a typo while posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure overriding a block and nested sub-block along with `{{block.super}}` is good combination of doing things. May be you want to re-factor your templates for not relying on this.

Here is a ticket on django related to this (not sure this has been fixed or not) [{{ block.super }} doesn't work with nested {% block %} statements](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7324)